# PowerApps - Change Border Color of Form

Tags: powerapps

I've added a form to a PowerApp by clicking "Insert" > 
"Form" > "Edit" and I would like to add "Hover border color" so when the user hovers, they see a border. However, when I click the button to do so, it just shows me this in the formula bar:

[image]

What am I supposed to do with this? (read: "how am I supposed to modify this to change the border color?") I looked for some documentation online, but can't find anything about syntax or the actual language that is used here. I'm not looking to spend x number of hours going through a walkthrough just to change a border color so I'm hoping someone already knows how to do this.

Comment: I've found this resource, but it still says nothing about how to actually change the property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/properties-color-border

Comment: I've also read a few of the tutorials found here, but none describe anything about changing border color: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/

Comment: Note: Border Thickness is set to 6 and style is set to Solid

Comment: Another helpful, but insufficient resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-forms-sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how am I supposed to modify this to change the border color?

Properties of controls in PowerApps can have either constant values, or expressions that reference other properties. For example, your control's hover border color is referencing the border color (I'm assuming of the same control), so if you look at the `BorderColor` property you'll find some expression that defines the color.

For the specific case of colors, the "constant" values you can use are either from the [Color enumeration, or a color name from CSS, or a custom color using the RGBA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-colors).

For example, if you want to set your hover border color to blue, you can use `Color.Blue` or `RGBA(255, 0, 0, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

You should try following the tutorials available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-configure-controls#configure-a-control-from-the-properties-tab. This walks through selecting a control that you would like to customize, in this case a forum, and you can use the properties panel to then change the border color.

You should make sure you have the right control selected that you would like to customize. You can see what control you have select in the pane on the left side of the screen, it will be highlighted like this:

[image: Tree view].

Once you have the correct control select you will be able to then pick the last option, like this:

[image: properties panel]

In the properties panel on the right side of the screen to customize the color.